# Loading extended library in Codeigniter with string params

Tags: codeigniter, libraries

In one of my models in CI i need to create a `SimpleXmlElement` object but I need to extend it first to use CDATA.

So I created a library:

```
class SimpleXMLExtended extends SimpleXMLElement
{
    public function addCData($cdata_text)
    {
        $node = dom_import_simplexml($this);
        $no = $node->ownerDocument;
        $node->appendChild($no->createCDATASection($cdata_text));
    }
}
```

Then in my model I load this library:

```
$template = $this->load->library('SimpleXMLExtended', 'xml_template.php');
```

But since `SimpleXMLElement` requires a string parameter (and codeigniter can only pass an array according to documentation) it shows error:
`SimpleXMLElement::__construct() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given`.

So how am I suppose to load this library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a codeigniter issue , it's how SimpleXMLElement is implemented.

This gives a very good explanation of what is happening and how to make it work.

[Previous answer from Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347510/extend-class-with-final-constructor-on-php)